# Cut video before uploading in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, video, upload, cut

I can use ffmpeg in js but how can i use this code in react

```
    const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path
    const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg')
    ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath)

    ffmpeg('video.mp4')
    .setStartTime('00:00:03')
    .setDuration('10')
    .output('video_out.mp4')
    .on('end', function(err) {
            if(!err) { console.log('conversion Done') }
    })
    .on('error', function(err){
            console.log('error: ', err)
    }).run()
```

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, you want to change a video file before uploading it?

I'm afraid this is pretty hard to do in the browser. Browsers usually don't have easy access to the local file system of the computer and have trouble reading and writing to disk.

The code you have included is meant for a node environment. A hint is the use of the `required` function on line 1 & 2 as node provides this function natively.

My proposed solution would be:

1. User uploads original (full-length) video to your server through a react app.
2. Server processes the file (using a node environment and the code that you have copied) and removes the first three seconds. A tutorial on how to receive  video uploads in nodejs can be found here: [froala nodejs video upload](https://froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/docs/server/nodejs/video-upload/)
3. Server saves the new file & deletes the original

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Well if you can upload your file to a server, wouldn't you already have the file access in the browser too. If not it would t even be possible to upload it to a server.